# Probability, taking balls from the box

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From one box containing five white and four black balls, two randomly selected balls were transferred to the second box containing two white and two black balls. After that, two balls were drawn at random from the second box, and it turned out that they were both white. What is the probability that two balls of different colors were placed in the second box?

I am really confused, but assume I need to use the full probability

P(A|B) = P(A ∩ B)/P(B)

Could you help me with the numbers?

Comment: Hint: if you are asked to find something like $P(A|B)$ and this makes you puzzling then try to find $P(B|A)$, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. If you can find them then you are ready because the general equality:$$P(A|B)P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)$$is then enough for finding $P(A|B)$.

Comment: @drhab I know about the formula but could understand what number (probability) to put

Comment: Finding e.g. $P(A)$ is straightforward. There are $\binom92=36$ pairs of balls in the first box and $5×4=20$ of them contain balls with different colors. So $P(A)=20/36$. Also finding $P(B|C)$ is not difficult. Finding $P(B)$ is the main job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have the first box with 5 white balls and 4 black balls and the second one with two white and two black balls.

Let us define the events A = "the first two balls were of different colors" and B = "the two last balls were both white"

What you want to calculate is
$\mathbb{P}(A|B)$

You can simply do
$\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(B|A)\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} =  \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(B|A)\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B|A)\mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B|A^{c})\mathbb{P}(A^{c})}$

So $\mathbb{P}(B|A)$ is the probability of taking two white balls out of a box with 3 white balls and 3 black balls and so $$\mathbb{P}(B|A) = \dfrac{3 \choose 2}{6 \choose 2}$$

With a bit of combinatorics these also follow:

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \dfrac{5 * 4 * 2}{9 * 8} $$

$$\mathbb{P}(A^c) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A)$$

Putting all of this together, you'll have the result

Comment: Your calculation gives $\mathbb P(B\mid A^c)=\frac{13}{15}$ and must be false (the correct value is $\frac{11}{40}$ but is actually not relevant). Further a split up in $A$ and $A^c$ is not recommendable here. We actually need a split up in $W=0$, $W=1$ and $W=2$ where $W$ denotes the number of white balls that are drawn from the first box. Here event $W=1$ corresponds with the event that you named $A$. The end result will be $\mathbb P(W=1\mid B)=\frac{10}{21}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $W$ denote the number of white balls taken from the first box
and let $B$ denote the event of finally drawing two white balls from
the second box.

To be found is $P\left(W=1\mid B\right)$.

This can be done by making use of the rule of Bayes and the law of total probability:

$P\left(W=1\mid B\right)=\frac{P\left(B\mid W=1\right)P\left(W=1\right)}{P\left(B\right)}=\frac{P\left(B\mid W=1\right)P\left(W=1\right)}{P\left(B\mid W=0\right)P\left(W=0\right)+P\left(B\mid W=1\right)P\left(W=1\right)+P\left(B\mid W=2\right)P\left(W=2\right)}$

Just find the probabilities on RHS and you are ready.